# Is not making /n need a Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm splitting some text so that I can find any link when I share something in my site, but it doesn't recognize /n and it shares all in the same line. Can you help me with a Regular Expression that fixes this?

here's my code:

```
function urlify(text) {
    var urlRegex = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/gi;

    return urlRegex.exec(text);
}


function parseLinha(linha) {
    return linha.split(/[\s,]+/)
        .map((x, i) => urlify(x) ? <a key={i} href={x.trim()} target='_blank' rel='nofollow'>{x} </a> : x + " ");
}
```

What I write: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvd27.jpg
The problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH7vV.jpg

Comment: I suggest using the multiline flag https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters

Comment: @JohannesH. I added the multiline flag but it keeps showing a single line.

Comment: That was just a suggestion for a more elegant solution, not an answer. But if you want to do it: Next step is to search for line beginings/endings. Splitting on  `/,|$/m` should now do the trick.

Comment: But your attempt actually works for just splitting a string with newlines in it, so your error is elsewhere

Comment: @JohannesH. Thanks for your help man I've found the problem thanks to your tip.

"But your attempt actually works for just splitting a string with newlines in it, so your error is elsewhere"

Really gratefull man.